# ButtonOnClick method doesn't invoke on first click

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, button, onclick

Everything was fine until I decided to put the buttons in a fragment. After I changed my code to what u see below app started to ask for a 2nd click to invoke button on clicks when it first starts. For example, when I click 1st button nothing happens but if I click it a 2nd time it invokes the onclick and keeps working as long as I don't restart the app; so I can click all the other buttons and when I click the first one again it still works. I would appreciate if u could point out the problem.

Regards, Wince

MainActivity;

```
    package wince.deneme;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.buttonfragment);
        final Button Button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final Button Button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        final Button Button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        final Button Button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        final Button Button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        final Button Button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        final Button Button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
        final Button Button8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
        final Button Button9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
        final Button Button10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
        final Button Button11 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button11);
        final Button Button12 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button12);
        final Button Button13 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button13);

        Button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button3.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button4.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button5.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button6.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button7.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button8.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button9.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button10.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button11.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button12.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button13.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        {
            Button Button1 = (Button) v;                   
            if(Button1.getText()=="Button")
                switch (v.getId()) {                           

                    case R.id.button1:
                        Button1.setText("1");
                        break;
                    case R.id.button2:
                        Button1.setText("2");
                        break;
                    case R.id.button3:
                        Button1.setText("3");
                        break;
                    case R.id.button4:
                        Button1.setText("4");
                        break;
                    case R.id.button5:
                        Button1.setText("5");
                        break;
                    case R.id.button6:
                        Button1.setText("6");
                        break;
                    case R.id.button7:
                        Button1.setText("7");
                        break;
                    case R.id.button8:
                        Button1.setText("8");
                        break;
                    case R.id.button9:
                        Button1.setText("9");
                        break;
                    case R.id.button10:
                        Button1.setText("10");
                        break;
                    case R.id.button11:
                        Button1.setText("11");
                        break;
                    case R.id.button12:
                        Button1.setText("12");
                        break;
                    case R.id.button13:
                        Button1.setText("13");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Button1.setText("Hatalı");
                        break;
                }
                else
            Button1.setText("Button");

        }
    }


}
```

FragmentActivity

```
package wince.deneme;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;


public class ButtonFragment extends Fragment  {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.buttonfragment,container,false);
    }
   }
```

Fragment.xml;

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button7"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button8"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button9"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button10"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button11"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button13"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button12"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Edit did a little debuging with putting a logcat at here;

```
Button Button1 = (Button) v;
Log.d("Db", "onClick: "+Button1.getText());
if (Button1.getText().toString() == "Button")
```

result is ;

```
10-18 11:38:25.422 23055-23055/wince.deneme D/Db: onClick: Button // clicked 1st Button
10-18 11:38:27.154 23055-23055/wince.deneme D/Db: onClick: Button // clicked 1st Button
10-18 11:38:28.838 23055-23055/wince.deneme D/Db: onClick: 1 // clicked 1st Button
10-18 11:38:29.702 23055-23055/wince.deneme D/Db: onClick: Button // clicked 1st Button
10-18 11:38:31.318 23055-23055/wince.deneme D/Db: onClick: 1 // clicked 1st Button
10-18 11:38:33.862 23055-23055/wince.deneme D/Db: onClick: Button // clicked 1st Button
10-18 11:38:38.954 23055-23055/wince.deneme D/Db: onClick: Button // clicked 2nd Button
10-18 11:38:40.678 23055-23055/wince.deneme D/Db: onClick: Button // clicked 2nd Button
```

Comment: What's the use of  if(Button1.getText()=="Button")..

Comment: Checking the text if it contains Button

Comment: But you cannot use == in String comparision...you need to do like `Button1.getText().toSting().equals("Button")`

Comment: hmm, then why the app runs as intended only needing a 2nd click? Edit; Just to be sure i tried both of them and it works both ways.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set android:focusable= true and android:focusableInTouchMode=true to ScrollView. it will work

Comment: Nope, it's still same